# Tabularx and colortbl conflict inside a savebox

Tags: errors, tabularx, boxes, colortbl

My overall goal is to build a table inside a savebox so I can easily fill the page with multiple copies.  Someone recommended using tabularx, which worked well until I also tried to use the colortbl package to color some of the rows.

In the MWE below, please note that...

1. Table 1: tabularx and colortbl play nicely together outside the savebox.
2. Table 2: tabularx works just fine when stored in a savebox.
3. Table 3: An attempt to store Table 1 in a savebox results in an 'Undefined control sequence' error.

Of particular note, selecting the "s" (skip) option on the console results in a compiled document where all three tables appear to be rendered correctly.  So, while I can typeset the document, it leaves me wondering if there is a "fix" to this issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\tabularxInBox}
\sbox{\tabularxInBox}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
        Col 1 & Col 2\\
        \hline
        Row 1& No Colored Background\\
        Row 2& No Colored Background\\
    \end{tabularx}
}

\newsavebox{\tabularxAndColortblInBox}
\sbox{\tabularxAndColortblInBox}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
        Col 1 & Col 2\\
        \hline
        Row 1& No Colored Background\\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        Row 2& Colored Background\\
\end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
No conflict with tabularx and colortbl normally:\\

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
        Col 1 & Col 2\\
        \hline
        Row 1& No Colored Background\\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        Row 2& Colored Background\\
\end{tabularx}
\vskip 1cm

No conflict with tabularx and sbox:\\

\usebox{\tabularxInBox}
\vskip 1cm

However, using both tabularx and colortble inside an \sbox throws an error:\\
\usebox{\tabularxAndColortblInBox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typesetting is not fully set up until `\begin{document}`. Sometimes it works to save simple text in an sbox in the preamble, but not here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\tabularxInBox}
\newsavebox{\tabularxAndColortblInBox}

\begin{document}

\sbox{\tabularxInBox}{%%%dont forget  eol
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
        Col 1 & Col 2\\
        \hline
        Row 1& No Colored Background\\
        Row 2& No Colored Background\\
    \end{tabularx}%%%dont forget  eol
}


\sbox{\tabularxAndColortblInBox}{%%%dont forget  eol
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
        Col 1 & Col 2\\
        \hline
        Row 1& No Colored Background\\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        Row 2& Colored Background\\
\end{tabularx}%%%dont forget  eol
}


No conflict with tabularx and colortbl normally:\\
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
        Col 1 & Col 2\\
        \hline
        Row 1& No Colored Background\\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        Row 2& Colored Background\\
\end{tabularx}
\vskip 1cm

No conflict with tabularx and sbox:\\
\usebox{\tabularxInBox}
\vskip 1cm

However, using both tabularx and colortble inside an \verb|\sbox| throws an error:\\
\usebox{\tabularxAndColortblInBox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  All the examples of savebox I have previously seen were in the preamble.  I didn't realize it could be "filed" inside the body of the document.